# How to add leading spaces to output column

Tags: sql, db2

Here is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT col1 AS MYCOL FROM table 1
UNION
SELECT col2 AS MYCOL FROM table 2
```

I need to add some spaces to col2 of table2 in output results so it looks like a tree:

```
MYCOL
row 1
row 2
  row 2.1
  row 2.2
row 3
  row 3.1
  row 3.2
```

note: just ignore rows sort/order.. Tell me how to add spaces..

Thanks

Comment: it's varchar data type

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in SQL?  This should really be a function of your reporting program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Concat(...) Function:

`SELECT col1 AS MYCOL FROM table 1
UNION
SELECT CONCAT("   ", col2) AS MYCOL FROM table 2`

Comment: Working for me in MySQL-Workbench. Where do you output the data?

Comment: OK.. sorry.. CONCAT does work.. .Seems my xPages project issue

Answer (score 1):

SQL's job is to produce the required dataset.  Beautification should be done at the front-end.

You can create an extra column to indicate the *level* of a row and use it for the appropriate formatting.

```
SELECT col1 AS MYCOL, 1 AS LEVEL FROM table 1
UNION
SELECT col2 AS MYCOL, 2 AS LEVEL FROM table 2
```